# Can i check on date in select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have two select boxes with dates. See here the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/egrba/
The people can choice two dates in the select boxes. A date for arrival and a date for departure.

But now my problem. How can i check on date. They should not be able to choose a date in the past. How can i make that with jquery?

Thanks for helping me guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of ways you could do that with custom JavaScript/jQuery code however there is an excellent jQuery UI component called [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) which offers a lot of really nice things for handling dates, including the ones you require.

[Configuration options](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#options)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a jQuery datepicker, which even allows you to restrict the dates that can be selected. Here is a [fiddle demonstrating](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/HfD6W/) this.